# Extending a rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, mechanicalturk

I need to extend a plugin by overwriting a method and adding one of my own. So far I have followed [Strictly Untyped's](http://www.strictlyuntyped.com/2008/06/rails-where-to-put-other-files.html) guide for this but I haven't had much success. Basically there is a file in the initializer folder that loads the extension from the lib directory.

In my initializers folder I have a file with this:

```
require 'amazon_extensions/question_generator_extendors.rb'
require 'amazon/webservices/mturk/question_generator.rb'

Amazon::WebServices::MTurk::QuestionGenerator.class_eval do
 include Amazon::QuestionGeneratorExtendors
end
```

Where I load the original class that I want to extend and then include my extension (Amazon::QuestionGeneratorExtendors)

Then in the lib/ directory I have a amazon_extensions folder that contains question_generator_extendors.rb:

```
module Amazon
  module QuestionGeneratorExtendors

    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval {include InstanceMethods}
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def ask(*args)
        case @type
        when :Basic
          askBasic( args.join )
        when :Formatted
          askFormatted( args.join )
        end
      end

      def askFormatted(text)
        id = "FormattedQuestion#{@questions.size+1}"
        question = REXML::Element.new 'FormattedContent'
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try and run this it still will not recognize my changes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the require statements.

So instead of

```
require 'amazon_extensions/question_generator_extendors.rb'
require 'amazon/webservices/mturk/question_generator.rb'
```

do

```
require 'amazon/webservices/mturk/question_generator.rb'
require 'amazon_extensions/question_generator_extendors.rb'
```